# get the elements number inside parent div jquery

Tags: jquery, size

I have a div that contain many images:

```
<div id="#preview_images_gallery">
 <img class="image_url pager" src="image1.jpg">
 <img class="image_url pager" src="image2.jpg"> 
 <img class="image_url pager" src="image3.jpg">
 .
 .
 .
</div>
```

**how I can know the number of images contained in this div with jquery?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#preview_images_gallery > img").size()
```

on second thoughts

```
  $("#preview_images_gallery > img").length
```

Comment: better than @Rory's only because it specifies immediate img children.

Comment: from the jQuery docs : The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Comment: +1, better than mine, although the OPs `id` already contains a `#` so the selector here is incorrect.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan true, but I reckon the op should change not me ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#preview_images_gallery > img').length
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imagecount = $('#preview_images_gallery img').length
```

the [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of a jQuery collection.

Note : you should change your div id from `#preview_images_gallery` to `preview_images_gallery`

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($("#preview_images_gallery img").length);//return numbers of images inside preview_images_gallery
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can count the img, in plain `javascript` way :

```
var get=document.getElementById('preview_images_gallery');
var allget=get.getElementsByTagName('img');
alert(allget.length);
```

Comment: My question is with jquery not with javascript. Thank you!

Comment: i just gave you the hint , its easy to build in any framework just not jquery