# number of elements inside a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get the elements number inside parent div jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483670/get-the-elements-number-inside-parent-div-jquery)

Is it possible to get the number of elements that are inside a div?

```
<div id=count">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
</div>
```

the resut should be

```
 4
```

Comment: you mean child elements or all elements in div?

Comment: The number of *elements inside* may differ from the number of *childrens of*. Which do you want?

Comment: Testcase: http://jsperf.com/children-vs-gt-star

Comment: Do you really think the answer will be that it's impossible? Have you made any research effort?

Comment: answer would have turned up in seconds in search on this site or google... at least try next time

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250688/count-immediate-child-div-elements-using-jquery

Comment: I think you should really consider using some filters for this, here's an excellent solution : http://jsfiddle.net/GYjh7/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$('#count').children().length; // 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = $('#count > *').length;
```

Comment: I'm for first answer before editing :) +1

Comment: +1 for a bit pervert approach :)